# Pinterest embed image does not show

Tags: javascript, embed, pinterest

I'm trying to embed a Pinterest link, like explained [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/widget-builder/?type=pin&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F379006124862874372%2F).

I've added this Pinterest link to a blog:

```
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/139330182194785581/" data-pin-do="embedPin"></a>
```

I've also added script `<script type="text/javascript" async src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>` before my `</body>` tag.

But the Pinterest image does not show. See a live example [here](https://www.toptrouwen.nl/artikelen/121/the-unplugged-wedding).

From the errors in the Chrome console I don't learn why.

What can I do?

Comment: I've noticed in the `request console` in browser, some status message about requesting the pin. Couldn't this help you in some way? 
`
PIN_1518090806339.f.callback[0]({"status": "success", "message": "ok", "code": 0, "data": [{"id": "139330182194785581", "error": "Not found"}]}) 
`

Could you try if that means something? If you could request any other pin? Maybe that might lead us somewhere.

Comment: Nah, that's probably just telling us: "There seems to be no error.". What if you try including this: `<script async='async' data-pin-hover='true' data-pin-round='true' defer='defer' src='//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js'></script>` instead of your one?

Comment: @MilanVlach thanks. See live version for the updated script. Still no error or  image showing though. What else could it be?

Comment: Could you try these tips under Common issues? https://help.pinterest.com/en/articles/website-widgets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a strange Pin there.
Looking into console I see that it is not found.

```
Request URL:https://widgets.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/pins/info/?pin_ids=139330182194785581&sub=www&base_scheme=https&callback=PIN_1518097590913.f.callback[0]

Response:
PIN_1518097590913.f.callback[0]({"status": "success", "message": "ok", "code": 0, "data": [{"id": "139330182194785581", "error": "Not found"}]})
```

When I go by this link https://www.pinterest.com/pin/139330182194785581/ in a browser - I am redirected to  https://www.pinterest.com/pin/379006124862874372/

So try the following code:

```html
<a data-pin-do="embedPin" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/379006124862874372/"></a>

<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that it redirects as stated above. From where would you be getting your pins? Because if it's a trusted source you should be fine, but if it's from user input you might run into this problem allot. Maybe you could try to write a bit of javascript to detect such flaws and display the correct one. I'm not sure how to go about that though.